# Front end upload for support staff only, not users

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, carrierwave, cancan

I need to develop a front end uploader for the support staff at my company. This is so the support staff can upload documents for the users to see, without going through the software engineers to update the new files. What type of authorization would I require? Is carrierwave and cancan the best way to go? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where there's an indicator/field that differentiates 'support' from 'engineering' staff.  Possibly in Active Directory where you could do a simple check to see if a person is marked 'support'.
No need for a more powerful gem like cancan.  Possibly use the activedirectory gem.